# python..I am stuck with one of the functions for and while loop

Tags: python

I need to create a game to be played n times and adds numbers from 0 to 10. First number is entered by the player, second is generated by the program. After that the player has to guess the answer. If it is correct the program prints'correct' and same for the opposite('incorrect').In the end of the game the program prints how many correct answers the player got out of n times.
 The game runs n times

```
>>> game(3) #will run 3 times
```

I got all of it working correct but then how do I get the last part which is the program counts the correct answers and get the message printed?
Thank you!

```
import random
def game(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        a=eval(input('Enter a number:'))
        b=random.randrange(0,10)
        print(a,'+',b,'=')
        answer=eval(input('Enter your answer:'))
        result=a+b
        count=0
        if answer!=result:

            print('Incorrect')
        else:
            count=count+1
            print('Correct!')

        print(_)

    print('You got',count,'correct answers out of',n)
```

Comment: Side note: `eval` on user input puts you at risk of running malicious code. See [Is using eval in Python a bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)

Comment: Move `count=0` out of the for loop

Comment: And replace `eval` with `int`

Comment: @AndrewL. Not when there's a better alternative: `int`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye You're right, didn't see that :)

Comment: @NehalJWani where do I put count=0 then? I am sorry, I am super new to python

Comment: @MosesKoledoye thank you for editing my code

Comment: @KameliyaDoncheva Just before `for _ in range(n):` , in the same indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Value of `count` is reinitialize every time to zero

```
def game(n):
    count=0  # declare count here
    for _ in range(n): # you can use some variable here instead of _ to increase code clarity
        a=int(input('Enter a number:')) # As suggested use int instead of eval read end of post
        b=random.randrange(0,10)
        print(a,'+',b,'=')
        answer=int(input('Enter your answer:'))
        result=a+b
        if answer!=result:
            print('Incorrect')
        else:
            count=count+1
            print('Correct!')

        print(_)
    print(count)
```

reason eval is insecure because `eval` can execute the code given as input eg.

```
   x = 1
   eval('x + 1')
```

user can give input like this which will result in 2 even more dangerous,the user can also give commands as input which can harm your system, if you have `sys import` then the below code can delete all your files

```
eval(input())
```

where this `os.system('rm -R *')` command can be given as input

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `eval`. You expect an integer from the user, use `int`.

Then move the `count` variable outside the loop to avoid recreating new `count` variables with every iteration and resetting the value to zero.

```
def game(n):
    count = 0
    for _ in range(n):
        a = int(input('Enter a number:'))
        b = random.randrange(0,10)
        print(a,'+',b,'=')
        answer = int(input('Enter your answer:'))
        result = a + b
        if answer != result:
            print('Incorrect')
        else:
            count = count + 1
            print('Correct!')
        print(_)
    print('You got',count,'correct answers out of',n)
```

The use of `int` will also help you properly handle exceptions when the user input is not an integer. See [Handling exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

P.S. On using `eval`: [Is using eval in Python a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)